# calculate CAGR using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a dataset which looks like below

```
ADVERTISER       YR     REVENUE
---------------------------------
Altus Dental    2015    5560.00
Altus Dental    2016    48295.00
Altus Dental    2017    39920.00
```

I'm trying to find CAGR - year over year and taking an average of them, meaning

```
CAGR = (((REVENUE(2016)/REVENUE(2015)) - 1) + ((REVENUE(2017)/REVENUE(2016)) - 1) ) / 2
```

And Finally I will need an output something like this

```
ADVERTISER      CAGR
--------------------
Altus Dental    3.75
```

How can I accomplish this in SQL? Please help me in providing an effective solution for this.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the CAGR (revenue/prev_revenue - 1) for each year and calculate the average CAGR (assume your dbms supports the `LAG` function)

```
select advertiser, avg(cagr) as CAGR
from
(
select advertiser, yr, revenue, revenue/prev_revenue - 1 as cagr
from
   (select *, lag(revenue, 1) over 
              (partition by advertiser order by yr) as prev_revenue
    from test ) t
) t1
group by advertiser
```

Comment: Nice one, I missed AVG myself :) It deals with the NULL value in the first row by itself

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
select advertiser,
       (((t16.revenue/t15.revenue) - 1) + ((t17.revenue/t16.revenue) - 1) ) / 2 as cagr
from t t15 join
     t t16
     on t15.advertiser = t16.advertiser and t15.yr = 2015 and t16.yr = 2016 join
     t t17
     on t15.advertiser = t17.advertiser and t17.yr = 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there won't be "holes" in the list of years. This should work for n years, and n advertisers:

```
SELECT advertiser,
       SUM(revenue) / (COUNT(*) - 1) AS CAGR
  FROM (SELECT advertiser,
               COALESCE((revenue/revenue_old - 1), 0) as revenue
          FROM (SELECT s.advertiser,
                       s.revenue,
                       LAG(s.revenue, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY s.advertiser
                                                  ORDER BY s.yr) AS revenue_old
                  FROM table_1 s))
 GROUP BY advertiser;
```